# Local files are removed after git pull -r from new repository

Tags: git

I have local repository remote pointed to GitLab repository. I wanted to push it to GitHub new repository. In new GitHub repository, i added gitignore and license along with it. I did following commands

```
git remote set-url origin <url>
git pull -r
```

The purpose of `git pull -r` was to add gitignore file and license (from the new github repo) to local project so i can push the project with those 2 files included. But the result was, git removed local files and pulled the repository.

Now project only contains following files

```
.git
.gitignore
LICENSE
```

I would like to know why it cloned the repository but not merge two files with local. Is there a way i can go back to previous state because there were some changes that is not pushed to the old GitLab repository.

Comment: Try git reflog - it will show you history where your branches were pointing to, so you can git checkout to them.

Comment: I could checkout commit before `pull` using reflog. Any idea why it cleaned the local files?

Comment: git pull does not merge by itself - you have to do it manually if you want to add some files.

Comment: What version of Git do you have installed locally? (That is, what is the output from running `git --version`?) Also, what do you mean by "removed local files"? Are they literally *gone* from your local machine, or are they just not present in the GitHub repository? And, one last question, *how many commits* did you make in the local repository before running `git pull -r`?